# Selectively serialize embedded object properties based on their depth

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

How can I customize the way Jackson serializes an entity that's sent in my REST response, such that my JSON doesn't become too large / unreadable?

Consider I have the following entities (or resources / models, etc):

```java
public class Department
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Employee head;
    
    // Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

And another one, like this

```java
public class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Department department;

    // Other fields, getters and setters   
}
```

I have a REST API that gets an Employee by his/her ID, and here's the response when I call that

```json
GET /api/employees/2
{
  "id":"2",
  "name":"John Doe",
  "department":{
    "id":3,
    "name":"Product Support",
    "head":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"The Chairman",
      "department":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Executive",
        "head":null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response, as you can see, is large (and can get really large depending on the data model). I want to stop the serialization from going deep into nested objects.

My preferred JSON response would be:

```json
GET /api/employees/2
{
  "id":"2",
  "name":"John Doe",
  "department":{
    "id":3,
    "name":"Product Support",
  }
}
```

I'm already aware that I can use the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on `Department.head`, like this:

```java
public class Department
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private Employee head;

    // Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

But this will skip serializing the `head` property permanently. For instance, see the below REST API call, post adding @JsonIgnore

```json
GET /api/departments/3
{
   "id":3,
   "name":"Product Support",
}
```

Here, I want the full serialized form of the Department object.

I want the Department object to be serialized fully, when I call `GET /api/departments/3`, but I want it to skip the `head` property when I call `GET /api/employees/2`. How do I achieve this in Jackson, when used in Spring Boot?

I also came across a library called [Squiggly](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson) that uses a GraphQL like query language for the API responses, but I would like to know if I can do without having to learn a new library.

#### Edit after Abbin Varghese's answer

I changed my `Employee` model to the one below:

```java
public class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"head"})
    private Department department;

    // Other fields, getters and setters   
}
```

Upon serialization, this gave me the following JSON output:

```json
{
  "id":"2",
  "name":"John Doe",
  "department":{
    "id":3,
    "name":"Product Support",
  }
}
```

The **pro** here, is that it solves my problem, without having to write a separate DTO class for my models.

The **con** however, is this: In this case, I'm trying to skip serialization only for the `head` property, so it makes sense to include this in the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation. What if the list of properties to skip is longer than the list of properties to serialize? For example, if my Department as 15 properties, and I wish to serialize only 3 of them, then it becomes difficult to include the 12 properties to skip in the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.

Is there an annotation that does the opposite (Include only these fields, etc.)?

Comment: I would suggest to define separate objects (avoid using db objects) to return data from get requests. It adds a bit of complexity due to mapping operations, but it allows to select data you want to return for every call.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk That is something we're definitely considering. However, I want something that can be done fast, as creating mirror objects for each and every entity is going to take time. Is there any quick solution or a direction I can take, considering the approach we already have now?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk That said, even if we create separate objects to return data from get requests, my problem with the nested objects remains right?? Stil then, my JSON response would have all the properties of my child object, irrespective of whether I want them or not.

Comment: You need something like WarehouseResponse and ClientResponse classes which should not have any common classes between each other. In this case, it is possible to control what is returned in the GET methods.

Comment: @SriramSridharan JsonIncludeProperties is reverse version of this JsonIgnoreProperties

Answer (score 0):

`JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY` is a good way to avoid elements.

For example..

```java
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MODIFIED_BY")
private User lastUpdatedBy;
```

Comment: Is this not similar to @JsonIgnore except for the fact that the "lastUpdatedBy" will be available for de-serialization? I tried this. However, I would like to include the "lastUpdatedBy" or skip it depending on the depth of the object.

Comment: Oops.. I obviously missed the real challenging part there.. :).. Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151132/how-to-get-rid-of-cyclic-redundancy-while-having-manytomany-relation-jpa-spring

Comment: From the outset, it seems to help. I'll try it out and let you know! Thanks

Comment: Hi Abbin, I tried the link, and it solved my problem. However, there's something else that I might need help on. I have edited my question with my findings. Hope you can help me out here!!

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if my Department as 15 properties, and I wish to serialize only 3 of them, then it becomes difficult to include the 12 properties to skip in the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.

I think you're looking for `@JsonIncludeProperties` that includes only specified props, others will be excluded