# How to get rid of cyclic redundancy while having @ManyToMany relation JPA springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I am a newbie to the Spring boot (but worked in Laravel). I am facing a problem of cyclic redundancy in @ManyToMany relation. Let's go through the scenario -

What response I ma getting (fetching user's list which has many to many relationships with roles) -

[image]

Following is the ER-diagram of associated tables to manage many to many relationship between `users` and `roles` table.

[image]

User entity class has following code -

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleted_at IS NULL")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE users SET deleted_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?", check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"}
)
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Name field can not be empty")
    private String name;

    .....
    .....
    .....


    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

And Role entity is as follows -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE roles SET deleted_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?", check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT)
@Where(clause = "deleted_at IS NULL")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"}
)
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    @NotBlank(message = "Title field must be not null")
    private String title;

    ......
    ......
    ......

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> users;

}
```

How to solve this problem? What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fetching the list directly. You will have to mention the annotation `@JsonIgnore` everywhere you have mapping specified. By everywhere I don't mean literally everywhere. Just use the annotation and see how it works.

Edit -> Just do it in roles table where you have mapped it to the user table. It will then skip the user mapping while fetching the data.

```
@JsonIgnore
 private List<User> users;
```

Comment: It's not like roles node in user list and users node in role list required. It's required but only once ....

Comment: Right now when displaying the result, your code goes in your user table, display the result. After displaying the verfiedAt, it encounter the mapping and go into the mapped table i.e Roles. Once into roles you have again mapped it with user so. It will again go to the user table. This process results in infinite loop. You will have to mention a break somewhere either in user or role table. If you put `@jsonIgnore` in user table above role mapping then while displaying the data the role column will not be there. If you put this above the user list in role table. Then only user part

Comment: will be skipped at rest of the role entity fields will be displayed. Since you dont need the user list again as you already have displayed user and then you go to the roles. so there is no need to do it again.

Comment: You are correct sir. But what should I do in relations like - Department and Employee both need to related data.

Comment: The Best practice would be to make a response body. Rather than just returning the exact structure of your database entity in the list. Make a response body containing only the data that is required by the client side team. Then format the data to the response body and then send the data back. This will help you maintaining a level of abstraction and you can change the response body as much as you like, without changing the schema of you database.

Comment: Working on ... but feel like more time to develop each feature. Thank you sir for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would probably be to annotate the `List<T>`'s with a `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to break the cyclic dependencies.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("users")
private List<Role> roles;


@JsonIgnoreProperties("roles")
private List<User> users;
```

Comment: I tried but not working thank you for your reply. Could you explain how can I set loose relationship, I am struggling around that ...  I got the possible solution would be set loose relationship between two classes.

Comment: there are various approaches to break circular dependencies when mapping with Jackson, have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion for further examples

Answer (score 1):

You could annotate `users` within `Role` with `@JsonBackReference`.

Comment: You would also need to annotate `roles` within `User` with `@JsonManagedReference`. It is a combination of `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference`which works to correctly render the response.

Comment: Not at all, if i went with role list then there is on users node. I need bidirectional relation here. Here role can be taken in consideration but employee and department cannot be...